# Remove certain background images - CSS

Tags: css

I have declared two background images in a tag called body

```
#body
{
    background: url("image1.jpeg"), url("image2.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

However, on a certain page, I want to remove "image1" but leave "image2"

Doing this....

```
#container #PageName #body
{
   background-image:none;
}
```

Of course removes both. Is there anything I can do in CSS only?

Thanks

** EDIT **

Thank you to everyone who has posted an answer. Re-doing the logic is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do:

```
#container #PageName #body{
   background-image:url("image2.png"); /* alternatively background:url("image2.png");*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way using CSS to simply remove an existing image layer and leave the others because of the cascade. You will need to specify "image2" again, by itself:

```
#container #PageName #body
{
    background-image: url("image2.png");
}
```

If your `background-repeat` values were different for each layer, you would also need to redeclare `background-repeat` so it matches the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #container #PageName #body
 {     
   background: url("image2.png");
 }
```

It ll help you. It removes image1.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-make it:

```
 #container #PageName #body
{
   background-image:none;
   background: url("image2.png");
}
```